# Gradle api execution failed for task - no errors found

Tags: android, gradle

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':ABCGRADLEMODULE:processProdDevelopmentDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:524)
```

I've seen these type of errors a lot, so the first thing I did was: went to `ABCGRADLEMODULE` manifest file and looked at (merged manifest) and only thing I found was: `(Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements)`.

I'm having hard time figuring out why is this happening... 
A little bit more information about my gradle file settings:

build.gradle: Project:

const val android = `"com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4"`

build.gradle: ABCGRADLEMODULE:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion Android.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion Android.buildToolsVersion
    flavorDimensions "server", "type"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        versionName '...'
        versionCode 5
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion Android.targetSdkVersion
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
        preDexLibraries = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        development {
            dimension "..."
            applicationIdSuffix '...'
            versionNameSuffix '...'
        }
        test {
            dimension "..."
            applicationIdSuffix '...'
            versionNameSuffix '...'
        }
        production {
            dimension "..."
        }
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${...}-${...}.apk"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'build-data.properties'
        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':...')
    implementation project(':....')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation Libraries.constraintLayout  
}
```

Then I have file where I declare:

```
object Versions {
    const val constraintLayout = "3.1.4"
}
object Libraries {
    const val constraintLayout = "constraintLayout...:${constraintLayout}"
}
```

Comment: hey can you send here your app manifest file here.. if possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `def` instead of `const`.

and you can skip the `buildToolsVersion`, because the `targetSdkVersion` defines that.

it should look about alike that:

```
def minVersion = 21
def compileVersion = 27
def targetVersion = 27

android {
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId ...
        versionName "1.0.0"
        versionCode 1

        compileSdkVersion new Integer(compileVersion)
        targetSdkVersion new Integer(targetVersion)
        minSdkVersion new Integer(minVersion)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I did nest compileSdkVersion (and other two) inside `defaultConfig`. Didn't change anything. Same errors, but merged manifests are empty (no errors).

Comment: @MaartinTheAndroidGuy if that is inside the defaultConfig does not matter too much... but your syntax is merely invalid. just compare what you've posted with what I've posted, once. you can't just use Java/JavaScript syntax with Gradle/Groovy. that nothing gets merged is no wonder, when the `build.gradle` has invalid syntax and also is missing the most basic configuration entries.

Comment: I updated my original post to full example of my gradle file. Can you take a look? I did have versionCode and versionName ect. declared. I have had this syntax for some time and I had no errors till this moment. Not sure what caused this. Is there some other way to check manifest merger errors? If the errors would be visible in manifest file, it would make more sense on what's wrong, but the fact errors are missing is little bit disturbing.